# sed separator (delimiter) replacement not working with p command

Tags: bash, sed, delimiter

I try to replace `/` with `#` separators in sed print command but don't succeed. Please look at the third line beneath:

```bash
u@debian:~$ echo A | sed -n '/A/p'
A
u@debian:~$ echo A | sed -n '#A#p'
u@debian:~$ echo A | sed -n s#A#B#p
B
u@debian:~$
```

How to replace it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Preamble

Reading the title of your question, I think you have to read quietly the *`address chapter*`* in `info sed`!

Understanding the difference between *addressing* and *commands*! `s`, like `p` are commands!

So your request is about *addressing* for *executing a command*.

#### Address range and address for commands

Little sample: comment all lines that contain *badWord*:

```
sed -e '/badWord/s/^/# /' -i file
```

More complete sample:

```bash
info sed |
  sed -ne '
    /^4.3/,/^5/{
        /^\(\o47\|\o342\o200\o230\)/{
           :a;
            N;
            /\n / ! ba;
            N;
            p
         }
    }'
```

- From a line that ***begin by `4.3`*** (chapter *`4.3 selecting lines by text matching`*) to the next line that ***begin by `5`*** (chapter *`5 Regular Expressions: selecting text`*) ,

  - On lines that **begin by a *quote `'`*** (or a *UTF8 open quote: `‘`*),

    - place a *label* *`a`* for further branch (*goto*),
    - append then next line,
    - if current buffer ***does not contain*** a *newline* followed by **one *space***, the branch to *label `a`*.
    - append one more line and
    - print out the current buffer.

This will extract, from `info sed`, the following:

```
'/REGEXP/'
     This will select any line which matches the regular expression
     REGEXP.  If REGEXP itself includes any '/' characters, each must be
'\%REGEXP%'
     (The '%' may be replaced by any other single character.)

'/REGEXP/I'
'\%REGEXP%I'
     The 'I' modifier to regular-expression matching is a GNU extension
     which causes the REGEXP to be matched in a case-insensitive manner.
'/REGEXP/M'
'\%REGEXP%M'
     The 'M' modifier to regular-expression matching is a GNU 'sed'
     extension which directs GNU 'sed' to match the regular expression
'/[0-9]/p' matches lines with digits and prints them.  Because the
second line is changed before the '/[0-9]/' regex, it will not match and
will not be printed:

     $ seq 3 | sed -n 's/2/X/ ; /[0-9]/p'
     1
'0,/REGEXP/'
     A line number of '0' can be used in an address specification like
     '0,/REGEXP/' so that 'sed' will try to match REGEXP in the first
'ADDR1,+N'
     Matches ADDR1 and the N lines following ADDR1.

'ADDR1,~N'
     Matches ADDR1 and the lines following ADDR1 until the next line
     whose input line number is a multiple of N.  The following command
```

#### In fine, regarding your question:

So you have to precede your 1st *delimiter* by a backslash `\`:

```
$ echo A | sed -ne '\#A#p'
A
```